# Want to fetch value of an attribute in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I want to fetch the value of aria-expanded from below xpath
//div[@id='contact-information']//div[@aria-expanded='false']

Which keyword should I use ?

Comment: Mention the relevant html code in your question, and specify the library used.

Answer (score 2):

Selenium2Library.Get Element Attribute should do the trick.

http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Element%20Attribute

example:
Get Element Attribute    //div[@id='contact-information']//div[@aria-expanded='false']@aria-expanded

Answer (score -1):

You can use the keyword [Get Value](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Value) that returns the value attribute of element identified by locator.