# Using Value obtained with Get Value

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I am very new to using Robot Framework, and I am using the RIDE development environment. I am trying to obtain a value from an element on a website, and then set a variable with that value. The keyword Get Value only accepts one argument from what I can see, and I cannot find any documentation explaining how to do this. This question is similar to another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38195935/want-to-fetch-value-of-an-attribute-in-robot-framework) but I am unclear on how to assign this data to a variable.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

--edit--

here is the element that i am trying to obtain data from:

```
<div class="highlight-box animate ng-binding" animate-change="master.user.balance.toFixed(2)" id="header-balance">
        0.00
    </div>
```

I tried setting the variable like this:

`@{balance}    get value   header-balance`

as suggested, and it didnt throw any errors, but then when I tried to use the variable with an input text:

`input text    Textbox-1   @{balance}`

it threw an error saying that input text requires two arguments. I took this to mean that the variable did not contain anything, regardless of being set in the last line.

Comment: Please provide some html code.

Answer (score 3):

To set a variable with the value obtained, just add the variable name as first element in your statement. Something like:

```
${variable} =    Get Value    id=my_element
```